# cakephp and class 'PDO'

Tags: cakephp, pdo

I have done with my first project in Cakephp, and i have uploaded the files to but get error with class 'PDO', i think this error because those extensions:

```
extension="pdo.so"
extension="pdo_mysql.so"
```

so i have to ask my hosting company to enable this extensions , my question is :
 1- is the extensions are safe or not ?

2- just the extensions i have to enable or there are another thing i have to do to make Cakephp work on my server ?

3- is something i have to do with my project before upload the files .

thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think you can find all answers at [book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)

Comment: i did all this things on my xammp and works fine , but on my server give me error with class 'PDO' ! so it didn't solve :(

Comment: Error: Class 'PDO' not found
File: /home/user/public_html/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php
Line: 169

Comment: Looks to me that the pdo extension is not loaded on the server. Can you try the following on the server: `var_dump( extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') );`

Comment: In that case you should contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable this extension.

Comment: could i get the script work with no pdo extensions ??, because my server has to have mysqllite extension, and this extension with pdo extension get the server down

Comment: I think it is not possible without creating your own datasource script.